# Calculate Date with IF statement

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Here is the ask: I need a formula for SP that will calculate the 1st of the next month or 1st of the second depending on the number in column titled week number.

```
class end Date    week number     30 Day    
1/1/2017               1           2/1/17   
1/28/17                4          3/1/17
```

I was trying this formula but i get syntax error:

```
IF([Week Number]>=4,DATE((YEAR([Class End Date]),MONTH([Class End Date])+2,0)+1), (DATE(YEAR([Class End Date]),MONTH([Class End Date])+1,0)+1)
```

Comment: that is supposed to be 1/1/2017 with a week number of 1 and the calculated date is 2/1/17 ; then 1/28/17 with a week number of 4 and the calculated date is 3/1/17.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're missing a parenthesis at the end to close out the IF statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missing parentheses, extra parenthesis, and `+1`s that don't make any sense.

`=IF([Week Number]>=4,DATE(YEAR([Class End Date]),MONTH([Class End Date])+2,1),DATE(YEAR([Class End Date]),MONTH([Class End Date])+1,1))`